# Python: Want to use a string as a slice specifier

Tags: python, string, slice, specifier

Suppose I have a variable `S` with the **string** `"1:3"` (or for that matter, `"1"`, or `"1:"` or `":3"`) and I want to use that as a slice specifier on **list** `L`. You cannot simply do `L[S]` since the required args for a slice are `"int:int"`.

Now, I current have some ugly code that parses `S` into its two constituent `int`s and deals with all the edge cases (4 of them) to come up with the correct slice access but this is just plain ugly and unpythonic.

How do I elegantly take string `S` and use it as my slice specifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution

```
eval("L[%s]" % S)
```

*warning - [It's not safe](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) if S is coming from an external(unreliable) source.*

Comment: You might want to explain *why* it's a bad idea (which it definitely is).

Comment: @user1814892 Please, please, please do not do this. It's not the tool for the job, it's unsafe, it's slow, it's just a terrible way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done without much hacking by using a list comprehension. We split the string on `:`, passing the split items as arguments to the `slice()` builtin. This allows us to quite nicely produce the slice in one line, in a way which works in every case I can think of:

```
slice(*[int(i.strip()) if i else None for i in string_slice.split(":")])
```

By using the `slice()` builtin, we neatly avoid having to deal with too many edge cases ourselves.

Example usage:

```
>>> some_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> string_slice = ":2"
>>> some_list[slice(*[int(i.strip()) if i else None for i in string_slice.split(":")])]
[1, 2]
>>> string_slice = "::-1"
>>> some_list[slice(*[int(i.strip()) if i else None for i in string_slice.split(":")])]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Much better to use split here over partition as I did to allow for the third arg.

Comment: Indeed, it works nicely. This one also works quite nicely at giving you decent errors for incorrect input (by complaining about extra operands to ``slice()``).

Comment: While this solution works, I think vivek's is much cleaner and easier to understand - something important for when someone takes over my code.